# Remove oldest file in Windows directory

Tags: batch-file

I'm working on a batch script that finds and the oldest files in a folder and removes them, leaving only the most recent file. I've managed to piece together the following script, however I can't manage to get the if statement to work properly.

```
@echo off
set cnt=0
for %%A in (C:\Test\*) do set /a cnt+=1
echo File count = %cnt%

pause

echo if "%cnt%"=="1" (breakLoop)
echo if "%cnt%" == "1" ( echo %cnt% file(s) remain! )
pause
:: if "%cnt%" == "1" ( 
:: echo %cnt% file(s) remaining! 
:: )


for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /a-d /t:w /o:d "C:\Test\*.*"') do (
    echo del "C:\Test\%%a"
     del "C:\Test\%%a"
    )
pause
:breakLoop
```

The script accurately displays the amount of files in the folder, which is confirmed with the echos. I'm intending loop the script until there's only a single file remaining, but the command prompt shuts down after the second pause.

I've intentionally added the semicolons to point out where it goes wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see no semicolons! Colons, I see - but not semicolons.

```
echo if "%cnt%"=="1" (breakLoop)
```

If the `echo` was removed, if `cnt` was `1`, then this would attempt to *execute* `breakloop` You need `goto breakloop` to skip to the label `:breakloop`.

```
echo if "%cnt%" == "1" ( echo %cnt% file(s) remain! )
```

Odd thing about `)` - it terminates the previous level of parentheses, but `(` in an `echo` statement is regarded as a normal text character. To have the first `)` interpreted as a normal character, you need to escape it with a caret `^` thus: `^)`

If you had run this batch from the prompt rather than clicking it, you would see `cmd`'s complaint about the syntax.

As for the `for /f` - well, if you were to use `/o-d` to sort in *reverse*-date order, then the *first* line encountered is the file you wish to *keep*.

See the `for` syntax by executing `for /?` from the prompt. You will find there's a handy `skip` option  to skip the first `n` lines of the list before processing it, so if you were to skip the first line with a `skip=1` then you'd save the youngest and kill the remainder.

Comment: Apologies, I mixed semicolons up with colons. The sole reason why I added the echos were for debugging. I'm intending to remove them, but I wasn't aware of having to close it using ` ^) ` . Thank you for your reply though, I'll try and edit the script.

Comment: :) the comment was a little facetious